# Topic and subject classification

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, markov-process, graph-theory

I have a set of documents that are OCR-ed and represented as a text file. I want to find out what are the documents that are talking about the same subject and maybe about the same person. I started to look if this problem has been  addressed in webpages. For example, I'd like to search for all the webpages that talk about the subject "terrorism." It doesn't have to mention the word "terrorism" but yet it should be implicit. Do you have any idea on where I can start my review?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest considering the following techniques:

- Using [Latent Semantic Indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing) to generate a text representation in which thematic concepts are explicit. This technique should find implicit concepts like "terrorism" and associate a number of words to them (a dimension in the word vector space).
- Then applying [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_clustering) to group documents according to that representation. The most popular document algorithm is Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering, and it allows you to play with sizes and number of clusters (groups of related documents).

Alternatively, you can perform automatic keyword extraction with algorithms like those implemented in [KEA](http://www.nzdl.org/Kea/). Then you can consider related all documents containing the same keywords.

Regarding persons, detecting them in documents is a problem of [Named Entity Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition); you can consider addressing it specifically with different techniques than previous ones.